# How to write data to a HID USB device?

Tags: usb, usb-device, hid

I have to develop an application to communicate with a [C8051F340-TB](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/user-guides/C8051F34x-DK.pdf) board from Silicon Labs through USB (just to be clear, I am using the P3 connector from fig. 4 of previous link, not the USB Debug Adapter from fig. 1). I have flashed the device with an example program that is supposed to echo the received data through the USB. However I cannot try it because I cannot figure out how to send data to a USB device. It is the first time I am working with a USB device at low level.

I am in Xubuntu 18.04 and the `lsusb -v` command says, among other things, this:

```
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 10c4:ea61 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x10c4 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
  idProduct          0xea61 CP210x UART Bridge
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Myself
  iProduct                2 USB communication test
  iSerial                 3 0001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower               64mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

which seems to be my device (I recognized the "iManufacturer" and "iProduct" fields).

How can I send a byte, or a string, or something to the device? Also, how can I read the data it sends to me?

Answer (score 1):

For HID devices, have a look at `dmesg`, find the corresponding `hidraw` device, write to or read from that (`cat`, `hexdump`).

Depending on what HID class it is, you may also get events on `/dev/event...`.

However, for HID devices, I'd expect

```
 bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
```

so you may not have programmed the device correctly. The HID descriptor (accessible via debugfs) must also be correct.

Also have a look at `usbmon` (accessible via Wireshark), and `libusb`, in case you can't get HID to work.